# Selenium Profiles Issue

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, profile

Whenever I open chrome using `selenium` twice at the same time, the first one gets the URL while the other doesn't. It's really weird how it does that. If anyone could help, that would be great!
These are my errors that pop up:

```
session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
Opening in existing browser session.
```

I have tried switching the profiles before opening each browser too.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\something\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 7')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

I expected it to open google.com on both of the Google Chrome drivers I opened. But it only opens on the first one.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `driver` can connect only with one browser. Maybe you would have to keep all drivers in separated variables `driver1`, driver2` and send `url` to both `driver1.get(...)`, `driver2.get(...)`

Comment: That sadly didn’t work

Comment: maybe you will have to run separated drivers in separated threads